# Повторная обработка сообщений в RabbitMQ, Golang

Tags: golang, rabbitmq

Смотрю пример работы с rabbitMQ на Go.
[Код из примера](http://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/go/receive_logs.go)

На основе этого примера написал свой код. Я беру сообщения из очереди и отправляю их на сторонний сервис для обработки. Если не произошло ошибок, подтверждаем доставку, берем следующее письмо и т.д.

```
    go func() {
            for d := range msgs {
                   docID, err = c.SendMsgToService(_url, d.Body)

            if err != nil {
                if err = c.PingPharmacyMDLP(_url); err != nil { //Ping сервиса
                    l.Log.Error("Ping", err)
                    time.Sleep(60 * time.Second) //Если нет связи с сервисом, попробовать через минуту снова подключиться
                    //Здесь надо что-то сделать чтобы заново попробовать обработать это же сообщение

                }
               l.Log.Fatal(err)  

            } else {
                l.Log.Info("Done")
                d.Ack(false)
            }
           }
    }()
```

Но, если сервис недоступен, выпадет ошибка connection refused. В таком случае я хочу просто подождать некоторое время, проверить доступность сервиса и если он доступен, снова отправить то же самое сообщение, на котором все остановилось. Как повторно обработать сообщение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать паттерн Очередь повторных попыток

**Очередь повторных попыток** — один из базовых элементов архитектуры приложения.  Используется, когда есть вероятность неуспешной обработки сообщения (как «временные трудности» в целом, так и проблемы с обработкой конкретного сообщения). Работает, если нет необходимости в строгой последовательности обработки, так как подразумевает возможность временного пропуска сообщения.

Существуют два основных алгоритма реализации:

ack+publish — когда consumer сам подтверждает сообщение из основной очереди и паблишит в очередь повторных попыток;

reject+dlx — через механизм dead letter exchange.

Взято из https://habr.com/ru/companies/slurm/articles/714358/